# Time complexity of a SQL select query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, data-structures, complexity-theory, b-tree

What is the time complexity of a SQL select query involving multiple conditions ?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
 WHERE price > 100 
   AND width > 100 
   AND rating > 100
```

For example, how does a database engine (InnoDB) process this query with an index on price, width and rating ?

Will the engine process the price first and then filter the results by width and rating ? It means first O(log(n)+k) 
with k the number of results and n the number of entries in the products table, 
then O(n) and then O(n), n being the number of results of every last filtering operation ??

Comment: Too broad, without a specific database (incl. version).  Even then, it depends™.

Comment: @OMGPonies +1 for the trademark.

Comment: @LibertPiouPiou You can't really say the first one will be O(log(n)). For example, if all rows will have `price > 100`, then it has to be O(n).

Comment: with the last version of InnoDB @OMG Ponies

Comment: @svick I've just edited my question

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking how the SQL optimizer works, and as pointed out, it varies on SQL version and it depends.

In general (very broad), optimizers keep meta data about tables so it can select which index makes sense.   For example, if a table contained student gender and GPA, you'd expect the optimizer to always use the index on GPA.   However, if you run the query at an all-male school, and search for woman, an optimizer might realize it is quicker to search gender column first (since very few records will be returned).    Also, if your table is very small, an optimizer might say, "the heck with indexes, I'll just scan the whole darn table"....

In your example, consider how many distinct values there are.   Are the column all integers?  If so, the optimizer could query the meta data and say "hmmm, there are only 300 rows with a rating over 100, and 10,000 rows with a price over 100, I think I'll use the rating to start with"....

But, as OMG ponies points out, **it Depends...**